# Transition for transform scale on html is only animating when mouse is moving

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

This is my simple code, which I want it to scale my whole document (html) with a delay of 1s (with javascript) and it should animate slowly the scale of the whole website.

In this fiddle, it is not really working at all - but on my file it actually animates it, but only when the user moves the mouse constantly.

html {
height: 100%;
width:100%;
transition: transform 15s linear;
transform: scale(0.6)

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector("html").style.transform = "scale(0.7)";
},1000)
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  transition: transform 15s linear;
  transform: scale(0.6);  background:url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/moroccan-flower-dark.png");
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without code that reproduces the behavior, I'm not sure what is expected. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], and what the desired outcome is.

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it work with your code so I modified it like this:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector("#test").style.transform = "scale(0.7)";
},1000)
</script>

<style>

html {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
 }

 #test{
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   transition: transform 15s linear;
   transform: scale(0.6);
   background:url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/moroccan-flower-dark.png");
 }
 </style>

<html>
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it seems to work as expected for me, whether I move the mouse or not. The issue is that the `background` on `html` or `body` tag will fill the full size of the screen even if zooming in and out or resizing.

EDIT:

If you want the background to fit the full window while the content is growing: I just added a `div` in your `body` to see easier what is happening. Is this what you want to have?

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector("html").style.transform = "scale(0.8)";
},1000)
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  transition: transform 15s linear;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  background:url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/moroccan-flower-dark.png");
}

body{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

div{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the html structure - so with html scaling its not possible?

Comment: And also if you use a wrapper #test, and set the initial scale(0.6) - not your whole screen will be covered with the background image.

Comment: I know I just kept the same scale modification you gave in the question.

Comment: Secondly, I am now not sure what you want to do: do you want all the website to grow, or do you want the background to fit all the page while the content is growing?

Comment: The provided answer is not zooming the background. I want to zoom the whole website! as a whole thing (background, any object inside, everything) - what you do is just zoom the div but not the background image as well. What I want is a slow camera-zoom like effect to the website. the background can grow over the window border (overflow:hidden). the whole site should zoom in.

Comment: @Suisse This is why I asked you. The issue is no matter what I do (changing size, zooming in and out ...), the background on an `html` or `body` tag will keep at full size of the screen. The only workaround that I know would be to set `background-repeat: no-repeat` and set `background-position` and have an image of the right size, but even with this the background would not be growing.